# CMake with Visual Studio 2017 exports .lib and .exp files, but not the .dll file

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(
        sensor_processing_c_library_legacy MODULE
        ${sensor_processing_c_library_src}
        )

set_target_properties(sensor_processing_c_library PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I want to produce a `.dll` in this directory. Instead, I am only producing the `.exp` and `.lib` files. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

When I do not set `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, the `.dll` is generated in the expected alternate location. Is it possible to adjust the destination of the `.dll`, or does it always go into the CMake build directory?

```
====================[ Build | sensor_processing_c_library | Release-Visual Studio ]====
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\dbak\Projects\firmware\cmake-build-release --target sensor_processing_c_library
[  8%] Linking C shared library sensor_processing_c_library.dll
   Creating library ..\..\..\..\testing\firmware_tests\sensor_processing\sensor_processing_c_library.lib and object ..\..\..\..\testing\firmware_tests\sensor_processing\sensor_processing_c_library.exp
[100%] Built target sensor_processing_c_library

Build finished
```

Comment: Is there a typo? Is the created library target `sensor_processing_c_library_legacy` supposed to have its property modified in the next line? Or is the `set_target_properties()` command supposed to be modifying a separate target?

Answer (score 0):

A DLL file is not an archive file, so modifying the `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` will not impact where it is placed. Instead, use [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) (and [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) as well if you want). On Windows systems, the DLL files are treated as *runtime* components, so set their output directory using this:

```
set_target_properties(sensor_processing_c_library PROPERTIES
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```